# How to POST a document with manual id in MongoDB database from Spring hypermedia-based RESTful front end?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-rest, hateoas

I am following this spring guide:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-mongodb-data-rest/

Everything is perfect, however if I want to POST a document with manual id, I am not able to do that.

Here is what all I have done:

I inserted one document from Mongo shell by the command `db.person.insert({"_id": "111111", "firstName" : "Vikas", "lastName" : "Prasad"});`

This works fine and if I do a `GET` at `http://localhost:8080/people` from Postman, I can see the person document with id `111111` in the response having self href as `http://localhost:8080/people/111111`

But if I am sending a `POST` request from Postman at `http://localhost:8080/people` with body as `{"_id": "222222", "firstName" : "Aadish", "lastName" : "Patodi"}`, the document is getting inserted with an auto id instead of `222222`. Because of which obviously I cant access this docuemnt by doing a `GET` at `http://localhost:8080/people/222222` unlike the case when I used `insert()` from the shell to insert a document with manual id. Instead I have to hit a `GET` at `http://localhost:8080/people/57bc29ada3fab115cc9b546b` to fetch this second document.

Just to check if I am `POST`ing the `{"_id": "222222", "firstName" : "Aadish", "lastName" : "Patodi"}` again, its getting inserted again at a new auto generated id: `http://localhost:8080/people/57bc2bdaa3fab115cc9b546c`. It means MongoDB is not even looking at the `_id`, else it must have thrown `duplicate key error`.

I tried searching various sources. All I can found is an implementation of  the data access code separately in JAVA at back end and calling respective MongoDB methods.

My question is:

Just like in the given tutorial they are performing every operation without defining any JAVA back end code for data access from MongoDB for auto id documents, is there a way to do the same for manual id documents?
Or just for this one use case I have to implement the data access code at the back end?

I am using CorsFilter to handle cross origin requests.

**Edit:**

Below is the `Person` class:

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

public class Person {

    @Id private String id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

I have tried:

-> adding getter and setter for `id` attribute

-> renaming `id` to `employeeNumber`

-> renaming `id` to `employeeNumber` and adding getter and setter for `employeeNumber`

None of the above three solved the issue.

Comment: can u paste your code ? one where you save the collection to db and the one where you declared the person pojo to map the id field in spring to mongodb ?

Comment: looks like your _id field is not mapped correctly.

Comment: There is no explicit saving of collection to the db as can be seen in the guide. The collection is getting created on first `POST` from Postman or from first `insert()` from shell, whichever occurs first.

The person pojo is same as in the guide. Yet I have added an edit.

Please have a look.

Comment: cool so the _id was indeed not mapped correctly.

Comment: @user641887 yeah you were correct. If you post the answer I can accept it.

Comment: i just did that.. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as discussed on the comment, looks like your _id field is not mapped correctly. Can you check if the _id is mapped correctly in the pojo ?

Comment: Any idea how can I access the id of a document on my client?
I am using AngularJS client and using `$http.get` to fetch all documents.

I am receiving the documents returning all fields with their values except the `_id` field. Of course, I can do some string extraction from the `href` field of `self` returned along with the object. But is there a better way?

Comment: till then, I have just introduced another variable in my class as `employeeNumber` and setting `this.employeeNumber = this._id` in the setter `set_id()` below the line `this._id = _id`. This way I can get the `_id` returned in disguise of `employeeNumber`. Not a great approach, but couldn't find a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got it working by renaming `id` with `_id` and adding getter and setter for the same in the `Person` class.

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

public class Person {

    @Id private String _id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void set_id(String _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```